# How to solve Angular FormArray and mat-select options linked to input fields?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a scenario where the user can open `mat-select` and choose an option from the dropdown. Upon his selection a hidden form will be displayed for him to fill it. Everything was okay with static (one) template. Now, we decided to make the `mat-select` and the corresponding templates linked to the options inside Angular `formArray`.
I have two problems that I am facing right now:
1- All `mat-select`s in all the generated forms listen to the same event (user selected option. That is to say,  when you change `mat-select` in index 0 of the `formArray` the `mat-select` in index 1 react to your changes.
2- All the generated forms appear with  the template linked to the option that the user chose from the 1st selection (index 0 in the `formArray`).

There are no syntax errors.

I guess the problem stemming from a global variable that I defined to decide to display one of the `forms` or not: (`isPremiumAmountSelected` in code below). I do not like to split my component to use `@Input` and `@Output`. I need a solution that builds upon what is shared below. (There are many related stuff depends on this).

```js
isPremiumAmountSelected: boolean = false; 
  FixedProductPrice: Boolean = undefined; 
  OneFactorPricingCarValue: Boolean = undefined; 
  MultiFactorPricingCarValueCarModel: Boolean = undefined;

  ToggledPremiumAmountTypeDropDownOptions(data){
    this.isPremiumAmountSelected = true; 
    if(Object.is(data.value, 1)){
      this.FixedProductPrice = true; 
      this.OneFactorPricingCarValue = false; 
      this.MultiFactorPricingCarValueCarModel = false; 
    }if(Object.is(data.value, 2)){
      this.OneFactorPricingCarValue = true; 
      this.FixedProductPrice = false; 
      this.MultiFactorPricingCarValueCarModel = false;
    }if(Object.is(data.value, 3)){
      this.MultiFactorPricingCarValueCarModel = true; 
      this.FixedProductPrice = false; 
      this.OneFactorPricingCarValue = false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div formArrayName="formArray" *ngFor="loop goes here; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="options">
        <mat-label>Available Types</mat-label>
        <mat-select 
        (ngModel)="selectedPremiumAmountOptionValue" 
        (onSelectionChange)="ToggledPremiumAmountTypeDropDownOptions($event)"
        formControlName="control">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options"
            (click)="ToggledPremiumAmountTypeDropDownOptions(option)" 
            [value]="option?.value">
            {{option?.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>                  
        </mat-form-field>
     <span *ngIf="isPremiumAmountSelected">
            <div *ngIf="FixedProductPrice"> Template 1 goes here</div>
            <div *ngIf="OneFactorPricingCarValue"> Template 2 goes here</div>
            <div *ngIf="MultiFactorPricingCarValueCarModel"> Template 3 goes here</div>
     </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve it few hours after posting my question. My approach was similar to **@Eliseo** answer below. Probably more straightforward.

**Step one: Delete the TS method and golabl variable**

These two should be deleted: `ToggledPremiumAmountTypeDropDownOptions()` method and the `isPremiumAmountSelected` variable. The other three vars should remain.

**Step two: Adjust the `ngIf` logic in the template**

To prevent the problem of multi-listeners to the same event I access the value of the selected option in every iteration `*ngIf` is inside it. (delete the span that hosts the `isPremiumAmountSelected` and put the logic below for every conditional template you have) Also, do not forget to clear the methods on the `mat-select` (It should be normal without any method).

Something like the following for the `*ngIf`s that will hide and display the templates conditionally:

```html
*ngIf="productCreationForm.get('formArrayName')['controls'][i].get('mat-select-formControlName').value === 'x'"
```

I do this with every conditional template I want to display.

That is to say I am verifying the value in the template. And with this i get rid of the global var  `isPremiumAmountSelected` which will be true always in every iteration based on the first selection.

Hope this was illustrative. The approach of **@Eliseo** below is feasible and correct I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general to mannage a FormArray of FormGroups that belong to a FormGroup you has a getter to get the formArray

```
get myFormArray()
{
     return this.myForm.get('myFormArray') as FormArray
}

<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <!--use formArrayNem-->
  <div formArrayName="myFormArray">
      <!--see that we use the "getter" before and iterate over "controls"-->
      <!--see the [formGroupName]="i" IN the own loop-->
      <div *ngFor="let group of myFormArray.controls;let i=index"
              [formGroupName]="i">
            <!--here you use formControlName to input the control, e.g.-->
            <input formControlName="control">

            <!--to know the value of control you can use, e.g.-->
            <div *ngIf="formArray.value[i].control==2">is two</div>
             <!-- or -->
            <div *ngIf="formArray.at(i).value.control==2">is two</div>
             <!-- or -->
            <div *ngIf="formArray.at(i).get('control').value==2">is two</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You needn't use three variables to know is if fixedProduction, onFactor or multipleFactor. If you want to use three variables, you need use tre arrays, but you can see that is unnecesary also is unnecesary the (onSelectionChange) event.

NOTE: You're using `(ngModel)' -not exist (ngModel)- if you want to say` [ngModel]` remember that if you're using FormArrays or FormControl, you should **NOT** use ngModel-,

NOTE2: In my answer I use some like

```
form=new FormGroup({
    formArray:new FormArray([this.getGroup(),this.getGroup()])
  })
  get formArray()
  {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray
  }
  getGroup()
  {
    return new FormGroup({
      control:new FormControl(),
      fixedPrice:new FormControl(),
      oneFactor:new FormControl(),
    })
  }
```

I don't know what are you using